# how to delete multiple columns in one pass

Tags: python, pandas

How can I delete multiple columns in one pass? I know this works

```
del df['A']
del df['B']
```

but

```
del df[['A', 'B']]
```

doesn't.

Comment: using `drop` method? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pystatsmodels/LPcCJem5vDE

Comment: I'd just like to add that the del statement won't ever work to delete multiple values because the magic method __delitem__(self, key) only takes one argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting multiple columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28538536/1278112)

Comment: You will notice that I asked this question in 2013, two years before the referenced question/answer occurred. Please find something better to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `.drop`:

```
df = df.drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1)
```

Comment: `df.drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1, inplace=True)`