# How to delete columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete columns that start the particular "TYPE" word and do not contain `_1`?

```
df =

TYPE_1    TYPE_2    TYPE_3    COL1
aaa       asb       bbb       123
```

The result should be:

```
df =

    TYPE_1    COL1
    aaa       123
```

Currently I am deleting these columns manually, however this approach is not very efficient if the number of columns is big:

```
df = df.drop(["TYPE_2","TYPE_3"], axis=1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting multiple columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28538536/1278112)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A list comprehension can be used.  Note: axis=1 denotes that we are referring to the column and `inplace=True` can also be used as per [pandas.DataFrame.drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) docs.

```
droplist = [i for i in df.columns if i.startswith('TYPE') and '_1' not in i]
df1.drop(droplist,axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: For some reason it does not work for columns that are named as, e.g. `TYPE_MOD`. So, the columns containing `_` are ignored. Why?

Comment: I just tested this and my column named 'TYPE_MOD' was dropped.  Is there whitespace in the 'TYPE_MOD' string maybe?  What do you get when  entering `df.columns[df.columns == 'TYPE_MOD']`

Answer (score 6):

This is the fifth answer but I wanted to showcase the power of the `filter` dataframe method which filters by column names with regex. This searches for columns that don't start with TYPE or have _1 somewhere in them.

```
df.filter(regex='^(?!TYPE)|_1')
```

Comment: Can you break down this regex? Thanks.

Comment: The regex has two parts separated by an or `|`. First half is `^(?!TYPE)` which is a [negative look-ahead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899422/regular-expression-for-a-string-that-does-not-start-with-a-sequence) used to find expressions that do not start with TYPE. The second part is simply looking for any matches with `_1`

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

```
unwanted = [column for column in df.columns 
            if column.startswith("TYPE") and "_1" not in column]
df = df.drop(unwanted)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t_cols = [c for c in df.columns.values if c.startswith('TYPE_') and not c == 'TYPE_1']
df.drop(t_cols)
```

Should do the job

Comment: OP says "do not contain _1", not "ends with _1".