# Dropping multiple columns in a pandas dataframe between two columns based on column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

A super simple question, for which I cannot find an answer.

I have a dataframe with 1000+ columns and cannot drop by column number, I do not know them. I want to drop all columns between two columns, based on their names.

```
foo = foo.drop(columns = ['columnWhatever233':'columnWhatever826'])
```

does not work. I tried several other options, but do not see a simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to use a comma in your list... `foo = foo.drop(columns = ['columnWhatever233', 'columnWhatever826']) `? Other than the typo the syntax looks correct, can you demonstrate what you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: No, I put `:` intentionally. If I understand, putting a comma would drop only two columns.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538536/deleting-multiple-columns-based-on-column-names-in-pandas

Comment: @AbinashBishoyi, of course I tried several options from that answer, but for some reason it did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.loc` with column range. For example if you have this dataframe:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  3  3  6  0
1  2  2  4  9  1
2  3  1  5  8  4
```

Then to delete columns `B` to `D`:

```py
df = df.drop(columns=df.loc[:, "B":"D"].columns)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A  E
0  1  0
1  2  1
2  3  4
```