# Python for loop not working on a dynamic script

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm using a dynamic script to remove columns with values equal to column name. Example below for table named summ.

Script:

```
for col in range(0, len(summ.columns)-1):
     if len(summ[(summ[summ.columns[col]].astype(str).str.lower() == summ.columns[col])]) == len(summ):
          summ = summ.drop(columns = summ.columns[col])
```

Input:
[image]

Ideal Output:
[image]

Output of the script after executing the for loop script above:
[image]

Once I re-run the script above, it would also delete the lname column but why does the for loop not check all columns?

Comment: since you are dropping the columns on the fly, the loop counter goes out of range after a point / it will skip columns. instead of doing on the fly, keep track of the column names, and drop them all at once after the loop
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538536/deleting-multiple-columns-based-on-column-names-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

```
colnames = []
    for col in range(0, len(summ.columns)-1):
        if len(summ[(summ[summ.columns[col]].astype(str).str.lower() == summ.columns[col])]) == len(summ):
            colnames.append(summ.columns[col])
    
    for col in range(0,len(colnames)):
        summ = summ.drop(columns = colnames[col])
```